# Capital Gains on a joint property

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gain

I own a property with my sister, she lives in the property and I don't.

We are looking to sell the property and split the value increase.

Would I need to pay capital gains on my half and my sister doesn't?

Comment: I've found the anwser here : https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-property/work-out-your-gain

Comment: Then put it in an answer, not a comment. And explain it, don't just post the link: the link should back-up what you say in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most likely you need to pay CGT and your sister doesn't.

If you own property jointly, [each owner potentially owes CGT on their own share](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-property/work-out-your-gain):

> If you own property jointly with other people,
>   work out the gain for the share that you own.

As your sister lives in the property, she's entitled to ["Private Residence Relief"](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-home) subject to a few conditions, such as not having rented it out.

You're not entitled to relief on your share but you would get the usual annual CGT allowance (about £11k at present).